# Memberships don't get updated when they elect to auto-renew

Tags: wordpress

We are using Wordpress and when a member elects to have their membership auto-renewed and we received payment for this in CiviCRM it doesn't update their end date, it still shows their membership expired.

Also, when it's a new member joining for the first time and they elect auto-renew, it puts their membership into a pending status even though we have received payment.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated as it's causing me to do a lot of manual updating on these records.

Comment: What version of CiviCRM and have you verified that the PayPal IPN call is coming through to the system?

Answer (score 1):

just to confirm some basics since your question doesn't specify if membership status update is happening for other situations.

For Membership Status to auto update you need to have the Scheduled Job enabled. You can see this on the demo site [here](http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/job?reset=1). And you need to have a cron running. Neither of these may be the issue you are facing, but are fundamental to the membership status update working.

Otherwise you should confirm your Membership Status is not 'overridden'. Again this is something you have probably checked but it helps if you can confirm such things.

It may help if you can clarify the Contribution Status of the payment. Is it being set to Completed automatically?